# Separate links from text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I try to separate links to images and videos from text, when reading rss feed.
Here is a rss feed `http://stopgame.ru/rss/rss_news.xml`

There some text which have description with youtube link, for example it ends with 
`<br><br>http://www.youtube.com/...`
 or some have ending with images

```
<br><a href="link"></a><br>
<br><a href="link"></a><br>
```

and some have videos and images

```
<br><br>http://www.youtube.com/...<br>
<br><a href="link"></a><br>
<br><a href="link"></a><br>
```

I need to separete all images links to array `$images` and videos links to array `$video`.
Now PHP is code like this:

```
    if (preg_match_all("/\<br\>\<a href=\"http:\/\/images.stopgame.ru\/(.*)\"\>\<\/a\>\<br\>/", $item->description, $images)) {
        $item->description = preg_replace("/\<br\>\<a href=\"http:\/\/images.stopgame.ru\/(.*)\"\>\<\/a\>\<br\>/", "", $item->description);
    } else {
        $images = null;
    }

    if (preg_match_all("/http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/(.*)\<\/p\>/", $item->description, $video)) {
        $item->description = preg_replace("/\<br\>\<br\>http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/(.*)\<\/p\>/", "", $item->description);
    } else {
        $video = null;
    }
```

But it show not very good result:
**var_dump($video) return something like this:**

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(46) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJc2W8SBE5U

" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "watch?v=ZJc2W8SBE5U" } }
```

**var_dump($images) return something like this:**

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(237) "





" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(188) "news/2013/03/15/1363362690.jpg">
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse html with regex? ;-)

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use simplexml:
Unfortunately, you didn't post the xml-file in a way that lets me understand its structure, so I don't know how to tell if a link is refering to image or video.
Unless you post some enlightening snippet of your XML, I'll give a general solution to extract all href-Attributes from -nodes:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('yourfile.xml');

$urls = $xml->xpath("//a/@href");

foreach ($urls as $url) {

    echo $url;
}
```